# Validators not working in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to use 2 validations for the same textbox(which accepts an academic year name for the input):

1. Regular expression validator to allow name to be entered only in format **YYYY-YY**. I have got this working :

   ```
   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="txtAcademicYearName_RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAcademicYearName" ErrorMessage="Enter academic year name in format YYYY-YY" ValidationExpression="(\b19|\b20)\d\d-\d\d" ForeColor="Red" Display="None"  ValidationGroup="AcademicYear"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
   ```
2. When the user enters the year name, the to value should obviously be greater than the from value( Eg. 2012-13 is correct, but 2013-12 is wrong). I have added a client validation function for this:

   ```
     function checkAcademicYear(source, args) {
     alert("yeah");
     var sAcadYearName = document.getElementById('<%= txtAcademicYearName.ClientID%>').value;
     var year = new Array;
     year = sAcadYearName.split("-");
     var yearStart = year[0];
     var yearEnd = year[1];

     var checkYearStart = (sAcadYearName.charAt(2) + sAcadYearName.charAt(3));

     if (yearEnd <= checkYearStart) {
         arguments.IsValid = false;

     }
     else {
         arguments.IsValid = true;

     }
   ```

   }

**AcademicYear** is a popup which opens on a button click. Now when I enter name in textbox as some string, it opens the popup(it should not do) but I can see the regular expression validator's error message in the popup.

How do I get both the conditions working?

Answer (score 0):

Are you call the **ValidationGroup="AcademicYear" in your button** ?

And **replace arguments to args**

```
if (yearEnd <= checkYearStart) {
      args.IsValid = false;

  }
  else {
      args.IsValid = true;

  }
```